# Teradata - How to find when was table last UPDATED not Altered

Tags: sql, teradata, insert-update

I want to know how to find when was a Teradata table was last UPDATED. Everywhere I look I am getting when was it last Altered. Is updated the same as Altered?

I got the code for Alter table :

```
SELECT TABLENAME, LASTALTERTIMESTAMP 
FROM DBC.TABLES
WHERE DATABASENAME = 'Schema' 
AND TABLENAME = 'table'
ORDER BY LASTALTERTIMESTAMP DESC
```

What is it for UPDATE table? Thanks

Comment: If AccessLog or QueryLog is enabled on that table you can search it for the last Update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good day!

To find the time the table last was updated, you can try to parse query log table.
For example, let your table name is TNAME and it is located in schema SNAME.

So you can use the following query:

```
select
    username,
    firststeptime,
    querytext
from pdcrinfo.dbqlobjtbl_hst
where 
    statementtype = 'Update'
and querytext like 'insert into SNAME.TNAME%'
qualify row_number() over (partition by 1 order by firststeptime desc) = 1
```

Comment: Ohh this is great!! I gave thinking I cant. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

In terms of SQL requests, `UPDATE` and `ALTER` are two different things.  `ALTER` modifies the table structure (`DDL`) -- i.e. adding / modifying a column.  `UPDATE` modifies the table data (`DML`) -- i.e. adding / deleting rows.

As far as I remember, there's no easy way to see when a table was last modified (updated) unless you add some custom auditing fields (i.e. `lastAlterTimestamp`) that you set each time you write to the table.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to know when a table was updated, you might think about using a trigger.